# How can we implement authentication in our application using azure active directory

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, cloud

How can we integrate azure active directory with web application for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@akhil - it would be good to know more about what you are trying to accomplish (sign-in only, call web api, others), your platform (ASP.NET, Java, JavaScript...). In absence, a good place to start is the [Azure Active Directory for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following links

[Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/)

[How to configure your App Service application to use Azure Active Directory login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication)